# SQLite: delete all records from table specified in another table

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

Having tables like this

```
mytab       deltab
---------   --------
id | name   id | name
 1 | Ann     2 | Bob
 2 | Bob     3 | Cindy
 3 | Cindy
 4 | Dave
```

I'd like to perform query which deletes all records in *mytab* specified in *deltab*, so only Ann and Dave would be left in mytab.

While there is [MySQL multiple-table delete syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), looks like there is no such thing in [SQLite delete syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

I am considering REPLACE syntax with select-stmt and mark the rows which will be deleted (like set these names to NULL) in DELETE query after. I wonder if there is more effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mytab       
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM deltab
              WHERE deltab.ID = mytab.ID)
```

Comment: hmm... a subselect, I rarely use them, how about their speed in SQLite? Is there any difference from Lokesh's proposal?

Comment: @JanTuroň:- I dont think you will face any difference in performance. I would prefer to use EXISTS over IN. As `in` is best used where you have a static list to pass. EXISTS will tell you whether a query returned any results

Comment: @JanTuroň:- Also as far as the speed is concerned I have found that EXISTS is much faster than IN(when the sub-query results is very large)

Answer (score 5):

Try this query

```
Delete from mytab where id in (select id from deltab);
```